# How to merge each object within arrays by index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How can I merge two arrays of objects of same length?

```
var array1 = [
  {name: "lang", value: "English"}, 
  {name: "age", value: "18"}
];
var array2 = [
  {code: "EN", text: "English language"}, 
  {code: "DE", value: "German", text: "German language"}
];
```

The goal is to create the following array:

```
var array3 = [
  {name: "lang", value: "English", code: "EN", text: "English language"}, 
  {name: "age", code: "DE", value: "German", text: "German language"}
];
```

The idea is to create a new array in which `array1` is the base and `array2` overrides the values if they share the same key, and otherwise adds to the base array. The merging should happen sequentially in the same order that the objects appear in each array.

In this example, the arrays contains two objects, but for my actual situation, I have a couple of dozens of objects.

This is what I’ve been trying to do, but this only merges the first set of objects:

```
var array3 = Object.assign(array1[0], array2[0]);
```

How can I loop through it or map it?

Comment: Have you written any code so far? Looks like a simple `.map` or loop would do the trick

Comment: So, you want to by index, merge objects together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: @Fallenreaper yeah that is the idea

Comment: @CertainPerformance i tried manually, but not with map. updated the question

Comment: @Xufox yeah that is right, i updated the question

Comment: Using object spread operator provides a cleaner look: `const array3 = array1.map((obj, index) => ({ ...obj, ...array2[index] }))`

Comment: You need to create an array to loop through the smaller of the 2 arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) will do it.
Instead of object spread, [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) can also be used.
Assign unto a new empty object in order to avoid mutating the existing objects.

```js
var array1 = [
    { name: "lang", value: "English" }, 
    { name: "age", value: "18" }
  ];
var array2 = [
    { code: "EN", text: "English language" }, 
    { code: "DE", value: "German", text: "German language" }
  ];

var array3 = array1.map((obj, index) => ({
    ...obj,
    ...array2[index]
  }));
var array3Alternative = array1.map((obj, index) => Object.assign({}, obj, array2[index]));

console.log(array3);
```

Note that the order of spread patterns and `Object.assign`’s arguments matters: latter properties overwrite former properties.

You can also add more properties, e.g. default properties: `Object.assign({ code: "XX", value: "Default" }, obj, array2[index])` or `({ code: "XX", value: "Default", ...obj, ...array2[index] })`.

If you want to *mutate* the objects in `array1`, so that the properties from `array2` get added into `array1`, simply remove the `{},` from `Object.assign({}, obj, array2[index])`.
Then it would also be advisable to change the `map` to a `forEach` if you’re not expecting to create a resulting variable like `array3`.

If you have an unknown number of arrays like this:

```js
const arrays = [
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
    // …
  ];
```

then you can use this approach:

```js
const mergedArray = Array.from({
  length: arrays[0].length
}, (_, index) => Object.assign({}, ...arrays.map(({[index]: obj}) => obj))));
```

See this in action with the following example:

```js
const arrays = [
    [
      { a: 3, b: 5 },
      { a: 7, b: 2 },
      { a: 1 }
    ],
    [
      { b: 8, c: 42 },
      { a: 1, b: 12, c: 44 },
      { b: 0 }
    ],
    [
      { d: 14, e: 15 },
      { d: 7 },
      { a: 10 }
    ]
  ];

console.log(Array.from({
  length: arrays[0].length
}, (_, index) => Object.assign({}, ...arrays.map(({[index]: obj}) => obj))));
```

Note that this also works with arrays of different lengths.
The resulting value from accessing a non-existent array index is `undefined` and spread syntax and `Object.assign` take care of this by ignoring it.
Just make sure to start with the longest array, so the result isn’t missing any objects.
This is easier with the snippet where you have an unknown number of arrays (even if it’s always two).
Instead of `arrays[0].length`, you just need to use `Math.max(...arrays.map(({ length }) => length))`.